# Angular httpclient get with params is not arriving at my web api method

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, http-get

Evening, so I have the following method in my (.net core) webapi

```
   [HttpGet("GetAllMediaWithTag")]
        public IActionResult GetAllMediaWithTag(Dictionary<string, string> tags)
        {
```

And I've got this in my Angular frontend

```
  getAllContentWithTag(): Observable<Item> {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params
    .set('country', 'Japan');

    return this.http.get<Item>(this.url, {params: params})
  }
```

I've tested my webapi with postman and everything seems to work just fine. 
A small piece of json in the body which it correctly identifies as my dictionary tag parameter.

However when I try to do the same with the getAllContentWithTag function, it doesn't work. It's almost as if the signature doesn't match.

Help please.

UPDATE:

I've been a fool, I've been checking out my console and seeing that angular creates a querystring. This is not what is being accepted by my web api. 
I've also added the attribute as you guys suggested.

Comment: For one thing, you need the `[FromUri]` attribute on your parameter in WebAPI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell that your parameter will be in query params. In your case your backend wants it from body.

To do it you have to add **`FromQuery`** attribute to your parameter.

```
  [HttpGet("GetAllMediaWithTag")]
        public IActionResult GetAllMediaWithTag([FromQuery] Dictionary<string, string> tags)
        {}
```